# I Want to add a view Controller on another View Controller for 5 Second?

Tags: swift, swift2

I Want to add a view Controller on another View Controller for 5 Second?

May Help me as i'[m new for swift programming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about creating an XIB and presenting it over the view?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this to make the screen disappear after 5s:

```
let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 5 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //put your code to remove the screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call another view controller and then on second view controller add 5 second sleep on viewDidAppear function and then again call first viewController.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
    print("Inside View Did Appear")
    sleep(5)

    print("After 5 second")

    let initialViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealViewController")
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is too many ways to do it.For my advice go with storyboard.If subviewcontroller only small part of parent controller you better to use container view controller in storyboard.If gonna use it like a overlay connect two controller using segue with "Present Modally" kind.You can find samples in google if you search for container view controller or segue connection.

For dismissing child controller if you choose segue way you can schedule self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil) code in second controller inside the didViewAppear method.For container view case you can write dismiss code in firstview controller and remove container from superview.